# I cannot solve the else part in my if-else ladder?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple program that iterates through the numbers in Vector to find the number the user asks for.
I ask the user to add random numbers to a list (the vector).
Then I ask them to enter the number they wish to find.
I used a if else ladder to check if the Vector is empty before looping through it. Else I displayed :"The list is empty"
I used a Range based for loop to loop through the numbers of the vector,
then I tried comparing every number in the loop to the WantedNum.
if a number in the loop==wantedNum, I assign it to wantedNum, then display WantedNum back to the user.
My code displays the wanted number but it does not stop there like intended.

The case I can't solve is when the user asks for a number that's not in the list.

Well here's my code (I initialized the vector explicitly with bunch of random numbers until I can solve the "Find a number"part, then I'll move on to the "add a number" logic)

I am a beginner so I'd appreciate explanations, especially what have I done wrong.. Of course advice is most welcomed.
Thank you in advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char selection {};
    vector<int> numbers {10, 20, 30, 46, 78, 100, -2};
    int wantedNum {};

    cout << "Welcome to my menu: \n";
    cout << "Enter F to find a number.\nEnter P to display the numbers in the "
            "list.\nEnter Q to quit\n";

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> selection;
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                cout << "Enter the number you wish to find: ";
                cin >> wantedNum;
                if (numbers.size() != 0)
                {
                    for (auto i : numbers)
                    {
                        if (i == wantedNum)
                            wantedNum = i;
                    }
                    cout << "Here's your number: " << wantedNum << endl;

                    for (auto i : numbers)
                    {
                        if (i != wantedNum)
                        {
                            cout << "Searching..." << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    cout << "Your number is not in the list.\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "List is empty - []\n";
                }
                break;
            case 'p':
            case 'P':
                cout << "The numbers in the list are: ";
                for (auto i : numbers)
                {
                    cout << i << " ";
                }
                break;
            case 'q':
            case 'Q': cout << "GoodBye !\n"; break;
            default: cout << "I dont recognize this input, please try again.\n";
        }
    } while (selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q');
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is very inconsistent and may be misleading. Edit : I've cleaned it up for you.

Comment: You search through the list with `if (i == wantedNum) wantedNum = i;` This doesn't change any state since you're setting wantedNum to the value you've just checked that it already is, so there's nothing you can look at afterwards to determine if you did find the number or not. Make a boolean variable for 'did I find the number' initialized to false, set that to true in your loop if you did find the number, and then test that boolean in your if-else condition to decide what to output.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you. I had ahard time pasting the code here, and properly format it.

Comment: @Rup Thank you will try that out.

Comment: imho already that you have a term for it is a problem "If-else-ladder". Maybe its just me, but if I see more than 2 levels of nesting loops and if-else I either refactor it immediately or run. A snarky way to put it: Handling code with 5 levels of intendation is a skill you need as much as understanding code that uses `goto`. A nicer way to put it: Use functions to reduce the complexity. For example in `case P` i would put nothing but `print_numbers(numbers);`

Comment: Read about [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: @Khalid_Zouzal You probably could have saved hours on this by simply running the program in the debugger and stepping through line by line.

Answer (score 2):

The following block of code

```
for (auto i : numbers) {
    if (i == wantedNum)
        wantedNum = i;
}
cout << "Here's your number: " << wantedNum << endl;

for (auto i : numbers) {
    if (i != wantedNum) {
        cout << "Searching..." << endl;
    }
}
cout << "Your number is not in the list.\n";
```

indicates to me that you are unclear about the logic.

You have to:

1. Look for the item.
2. If the item is found, set some flag to indicate that the item was found. Break out of the look when the item is found. Continuing to loop through the numbers after the item is found does not serve any purpose.
3. Print a message as appropriate after the end of the loop.

Here's an updated version

```
bool found = false;
for (auto i : numbers) {
    if (i == wantedNum)
    {
       found = true;
       break;
    }
}

if ( found )
{
   cout << "Found " << wantedNum << " in the list.\n"
}
else
{
   cout << "Did not find " << wantedNum << " in the list.\n"
}
```

You can use `std::find` to reduce the amout of code a little bit.

```
bool found = (std::find(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), wantedNum) != numbers.end());

if ( found )
{
   cout << "Found " << wantedNum << " in the list.\n"
}
else
{
   cout << "Did not find " << wantedNum << " in the list.\n"
}
```